# wxPython - Best way to detect no input change?

Tags: python, python-3.x, wxpython

I have a GUI with wxPython managing the Inputs for my SQL Queries. I need to check if any input (TextCtrl, ComboBox etc.) was changed.

What is the best way to do that? Do i really need to save all inputs anywhere?

Sorry for providing no code, but i dont think it will support my question to just post a small wxPython Tool.

Comment: Each input will fire an event. Each event can be used to set the same variable (eg self.input_occurred=True). Then at least you know something has to be updated. However I suspect you haven't included in your question all that you want.

Comment: So i do need to bind every widget which can have an event like that?

Comment: That's one way. Another would be to check each item at some `end` point but without being able to see what you are trying to achieve, it's hard to say. That's one of the drawbacks to not posting code, the question becomes theoretical.

Answer (score 0):

## Try this //sw

Note: I dont know how wxPython works only pygame and tkinter

Have a idle function for checking with _thread

```
import _thread

def this_function_should_return_the_text_of_the_inputbox():
    
    return content_of_the_inputbox

def  this_function_will_be_called_if_the_inputbox_is_changed():

    Do something


def idle_checking():

    latest_check = this_function_should_return_the_text_of_the_inputbox()
    
    while True:

        check = this_function_should_return_the_text_of_the_inputbox()

        if latest_check != check:
            
            latest_check = check

            this_function_will_be_called_if_the_inputbox_is_changed()

            
            

_thread.start_new_thread(idle_checking,())
```